# Convert 01/01/1904 to OpenOffice default 12/30/1899

Tags: libreoffice

I have a LibreOffice spreadsheet with many hundreds of cells going back 8 years.

I always seem to have trouble pasting dates into this particular spreadsheet and I have discovered that the date format is set to 01/01/1904 rather than the LibreOffice default 12/30/1899 as in all my other spreadsheets.

Is there any simple way of converting all the dates without recreating the spreadsheet?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Tetsujin I was unsure where to post but chose this as I understood the 01/01/1904 was a Mac "standard" If not I will post on another site

Comment: The 1899 & 1900 systems stem from a bug in Lotus 123. The Mac 1904 system avoids the bug. Different spreadsheets chose different systems, LibreOffice changed from Lotus to 1899 as default… idk why. Most can change base date in prefs. https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060102.html?DbPAR=CALC

Comment: @Tetsujin It is possible to change default but then all dates are off by 4 years and I would like to avoid this. Most of my spreadsheets started on Windows.

Comment: @Tetsujin questions about the use of software running on macOS are in-topic.